# How to disable wrapping in HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app, and having trouble with my header component. Its elements are wrapping with small screen sizes, and I would like them not to.

Here's the goal:

[image: Good-form heading]

Here's what's happening now:

[image: The problematic situation]

I know I could set a fixed width to the header, but I would like not to. I also wouldn't like to use JavaScript to calculate the width.

Here's the HTML/Angular/Ionic code for the title component:

```
<h1 *ngIf="backButton; else titleBackButton">{{ title }}</h1> <!-- show if backButton != true -->
<ng-template #titleBackButton> <!-- show if backButton == true -->
  <button ion-button round class="button-back">
    <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <h1 class="floated-title">{{ title }}</h1> <!-- this has been floated to the right -->
</ng-template>
```

Here are my CSS styles:

```
.button-back {
  margin: 17px 0 0 10px;
}

.floated-title {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Either go smaller on the font size on mobile ... or allow the word itself to break, either using soft hyphens in the HTML code already (more control), or CSS properties `overflow-wrap` and/or `hyphens` ...? (Which seems to be something you somehow achieved for the other items further down already, so ...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any time you want to force elements to line-up in a row, and never wrap, give the parent container `display: flex`. This automatically applies `flex-wrap: nowrap` and `flex-direction: row`.

The above suggestion applies to plain CSS. Some frameworks may set different defaults.

For instance, in React, `flex-direction` defaults to `column`.

Alternatively, you can apply `white-space: nowrap` to the container, which suppresses all line breaks inside the container.